# Windows 8 style window manager for Linux

Tags: window-manager, tiling-wm

Are there any windows managers out there for Linux that offers the "metro" style window management that Windows 8 offers?

Actually it's not just Windows 8 that offers the style I'm looking for. iOS, Android and tablets in general seem to take a simpler approach to window management that I'm attracted to.

I've heard about tiling managers, which I suspect might be what I am looking for,  but from [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/23752/are-there-any-linux-distro-that-features-a-tiling-window-manager-as-main-wm) I get the impression that they are most often geared for more experienced users who are willing to spend the time to really customize their environment.

Are there such window managers for the less apt user?

Comment: I always thought metro was an application-launching thing, and iOS, Android, and tablets tend to take a "one window at a time, filling the whole screen" approach, which isn't exactly window management. What exactly are you looking for?

Comment: I don't know what "Metro style" is, but is not the Unity that Ubuntu is working on targeted for tablets?

Comment: @MichaelMrozek basically they do the "filling the whole screen" approach, but they do a little more to make it convenient to browse through various applications that you have open. For instance, on the iPad you can "push up" with four or more fingers to show the list of open applications where you can either switch to them, or close them.

Comment: What do you mean with "metro style"? Do you mean the ability to tile windows to the top, left, right and bottom by hitting WINDOWS+ARROW?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer to your first question is: No.

But, there are window managers that can be configured to look and behave almost exactly like you want.

The answer to your second question is: Yes.

There are several window managers that are easy to use, without needing to configure them.
However, what is percieved as "ease of use", varies from user to user and also depends on which system(s) they are used to before. If you're used to Windows 95, IceWM might work for you. If you're used to Windows XP, Gnome 2 or KDE might do the trick. It's also usually possible to "theme" windowmanagers and make them look like other systems. Some windowmanagers doesn't look anything like Windows, but are relatively easy to use, like BlackBox, OpenBox and PekWM. Good luck finding one that suits you.

Answer (score 1):

"[Rat Poison](http://www.nongnu.org/ratpoison/)" will do whatever you want it to. It will let you put any program you want in borderless panes exactly where you want them on the monitor, precisely the size you want, using every valuable pixel of space. It is controlled by key strokes, not the mouse ( hence the name "rat poison" ). It is amazingly configurable. You can launch programs with hot keys, launch programs with "ratmenu", kill programs at will, or launch programs at start-up. Rat Poison is nothing like Microsoft, and that's a good thing.